# WINUI 3 Window Border Color

Tags: c#, colors, border, winui

I would like to know how to set the color of the main window in a WINUI 3 C# application. By default, it matches whatever theme color is applied to the Windows computer. In this example, it is a purple color. Can I set/override this color with a specific color of my own?
[image: Purple Color Example]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible "for the moment".

I tried overriding the ThemeResources but it only applied to the controls inside  the app not its window border. But there is a discussion on GitHub to make the app window **borderless**, so there's a chance that they make it possible to change the border color.

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1247